# Historical Statistical Analysis on the Length of Court Proceedings in the US?

Tags: united-states, law, statistics

Hello, all. I have been trying to find (and have failed, thus far) historical analyses of the average length of time court cases take, from start to finish, in the United States over time.

I have a theory that, as a proxy for the increasing complexities of the legal system over time, court cases - across all categories (civil, federal, etc) - should also be taking significantly longer, and I am now trying to find evidence of that.

If anyone could point me in the direction of such statistical research - even where to look - I would extremely appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Find the case records of the court(s) you are interested in; calculate the duration of a representative sample of cases; compare.

Comment: Someone suggested that this be migrated to law; consensus is that this is too broad for law.

Comment: Collecting such a sample, over time, would still be manageable by an individual, but what would really be useful is all the accompanying data on the trials within the collected sample, with enough data to run a basic regression. This way, also a perspective on which factors most influence trial-lengths over time is given. The most basic statistical analysis would accomplish this. However, gathering all the data would require a dedicated historian, at the very least.

Comment: There seems to be a site, the [Bureau of Justice Statistics](https://www.bjs.gov/), which may be helpful to you.

Comment: FWIW unless something has changed in the past 2 years, the data is not publicly available in a useful format. The reason I'm writing this is that there are a number of businesses that revolve around scraping this data from various courthouses across the US and elsewhere. Lawyers et al can usually access court records, but they typically do so by accessing individual documents one by one, rather than in aggregate as a data dump. Still, a few courthouses offered APIs if memory serves me well, so you might be able to build a large sample to test your hypothesis.

Comment: Oh, and... there's a term for what you want to touch onto: [legislative inflation](https://content.sciendo.com/view/journals/bjlp/4/2/article-p78.xml).

Comment: That is very interesting to hear, Denis de Bernardy. I will look into that as well to see how easy this task would be.

Comment: @Coolio2654 - You might [Court Statistics Project](http://www.courtstatistics.org/) useful. And no, "_legislative inflation_" is not relevant to your stated purpose (as I understand from your question), as it deals mainly with legislature, not judicature. Your enquiry is related to, broadly, "Economics of Law", [an example article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/765074?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). There are major research on this topic; try searching for "access to justice" within Economics of Law. Good luck.

Comment: @Coolio2654: there might be some [publicly available stats](https://www.uscourts.gov/statistics-reports/analysis-reports/federal-court-management-statistics) from federal courts. IMO ask them if they have some data.

Comment: Are you open to purchasing the relevant data and doing the computations yourself?  Or is data purchase not in your budget?

Comment: It is not within my budget, as I am a simple recently graduated student-citizen wanting to shed light on an issue, but the source of such information is incredibly important to me, because then I can at least start *somewhere*, and think about getting it, because the computations would be completely within my grasp.

Comment: @Coolio2654: if the computations are within your grasp then you can likely learn enough Python to use Scrapy, and if so your problem is basically solved if you've enough time on your hands.

Comment: By the way, focusing on trials is misguided.  The vast majority of suits settle before trial, but a slow legal system also delays settlements.

Comment: A trial ending in a "settle" would just be one of the three outcomes that could be assigned to each trial in the data.

Comment: @Coolio2654 I think you are missing that many (and probably most) settlements are pre-trial.

Answer (score 1):

There are databases of specific types of suits, some of which are free.  For a long-established example, consider the comprehensive database Stanford has created of securities class actions.  See http://securities.stanford.edu/stats.html for more detail.  If you are good at mining text data, that source is rich.  In particular, it includes information on settlements, not merely on judgments.   (Of course, it's only for class actions that you can expect data on settlements since they often aren't public for other types of suits. )